springboot in docker :Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction
my springboot project run in docker ,I got error:
    "errMsg": "org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!"

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11-jre
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/basic-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war app.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.war"]

application.properties
server.port=8080
#add /basic-webapp prefix
server.servlet.context-path=/basic-webapp

#DataSource
#database drive
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#database connection
#jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/O2O?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/O2O
#database username(encrypted)
jdbc.username=WnplV/ietfQ=
#database password(encrypted)
jdbc.password=uuXQXMpmyRf1BZsHVampaA==

#Mybatis 
mybatis_config_file=mybatis-config.xml
mapper_path=/mapper/**.xml
type_alias_package=infinity.com.O2O.entity

#Redis settings
#redis.hostname=127.0.0.1
redis.hostname=redis
redis.port=6379
redis.pool.maxActive=100
redis.pool.maxIdle=20
redis.pool.maxWait=3000
redis.pool.testOnBorrow=true


#path settings
pathWin=D:/projectdev/image/
pathMac=/Users/admin/Image/
pathLinux=/home/admin/image/
pathShop=upload/item/shop/
headline.relevant.path=upload/item/headline/
shopcategory.relevant.path=upload/item/shopcategory/




spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
jwt.secret=usertoken
jwt.expiration=40



docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: O2O
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwer123456
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/travel-life-backend/O2O.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend_network

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - backend_network

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: travel-life-backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend_network

volumes:
  mysql_data:
  redis_data:

networks:
  backend_network:

I have checked the database in the MySQL container, and there are no issues. I can access the MySQL container from the Spring Boot container using the username and password. The decrypted MySQL username and password are also correct. The Spring Boot and MySQL containers are in the same network.
